# Add Button action to subview of MPMoviePlayerController- swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller

Here i use to get video from gallery and merge with audio and display the final video to screen.And i use `MPMoviePlayerController` to display the merged video. Here i added one button on subview of that `MPMoviePlayerController` . when that button click my video should play in new player or it also may be some view controller,

Needed:

I have try to add button on subview of that video player in my screen .But no able to do the action method

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        button   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
        button.frame = CGRectMake(34, 449, 220, 106)

        button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

       self.view.addSubview(button)
        button.hidden = true

    }
```

Here the action:

```
func buttonAction(sender:NSNotification?){
       print("finishPreload");
    }
```

Here when my merge video didfinish:

```
    func exportDidFinish(session: AVAssetExportSession) {
        if session.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Completed {
            let outputURL = session.outputURL
            let library = ALAssetsLibrary()
            if library.videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(outputURL) {
                library.writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputURL,
                    completionBlock: { (assetURL:NSURL!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
                        var title = ""
                        var message = ""
                        if error != nil {
                            title = "Error"
                            message = "Failed to save video"





                        } else {



//                            AVAsset *asset = AVAsset assetWithURL: outputURL

                            self.videoURL = outputURL!

                            self.mediaUI.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                            self.videoPlayer = MPMoviePlayerController()
                            self.videoPlayer.contentURL = self.videoURL


                            self.videoPlayer.controlStyle = .Embedded

                           self.videoPlayer.scalingMode = .AspectFill

                            self.videoPlayer.shouldAutoplay = true


                            self.videoPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(34, 449, 220, 106)

                              self.view.addSubview(self.videoPlayer.view)

                            self.videoPlayer.play()
                            self.videoPlayer.prepareToPlay()

                          self.button.hidden = false







                            title = "Success"
                            message = "Video saved"
                        }
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))
                        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                })
            }
        }

      //  activityMonitor.stopAnimating()
        firstAsset = nil
        secondAsset = nil
        audioAsset = nil
    }
```

i create this button for the reason when i touch my video player in my screen it should play the video in new player or next viewcontroller. For that i kept the button action. But not able to do button action method.

Thanks!

**NOTE:**

If its not possible .then there is any alternate solution - when i click the merged video that displaying in my screen it should play in another player or line another new screen